# Union SQL query in php

Tags: mysql, sql, union

I have a problem while trying to link 5 tables using the `UNION` SQL query. One of the problems is the number of elements I require from each SQL query separated by `UNION` is different. And when I use '' in the query to make number of elements in each query equal, it just displays result from the first query only. Here is the query which links 5 tables.

```
(SELECT a.a1,b.b1 
      FROM a,b 
     WHERE a.a2 = b.b2) 
   UNION
   (SELECT a.a1,c.c1 
      FROM a,c 
     WHERE a.a3 = c.c3) 
   UNION
   (SELECT a.a1,d.d1,d.d2 
      FROM a,d 
     WHERE a.a4 = d.d4) 
   UNION
   (SELECT a.a1,e.e1,e.e2,e.e3 
      FROM a,e 
     WHERE a.a5 = e.e5)
```

This shows an error, while when I rewrite it so as to make the number of elements equal (here 4) as:

```
(SELECT a.a1,b.b1,'','' 
      FROM a,b 
 WHERE a.a2 = b.b2) 
UNION
(SELECT a.a1,c.c1,'','' 
   FROM a,c 
  WHERE a.a3 = c.c3) 
UNION
(SELECT a.a1,d.d1,d.d2,'' 
   FROM a,d 
  WHERE a.a4 = d.d4) 
UNION
(SELECT a.a1,e.e1,e.e2,e.e3 
   FROM a,e 
  WHERE a.a5 = e.e5)
```

I get only the result from 1st query ie, result of SELECT a.a1,b.b1,'','' from a,b where a.a2 = b.b2 alone

Comment: `UNION` says that the number of columns trying to fetch must be same.

Comment: yes so i used '', to make columns returned same, but then i get only result of 1st query (actually there are 4 queries seperated by union)

Comment: are you sure that you are getting result from only first query? Cause, the resultant column name would be same as first query

Comment: To add to what Rahul says, it is true that the combined union query will show only the names of columns from first select. May be, so you are misinterpreting as the results from only the first query are showing up. OKie now to validate it - the only way is to just fire those 5 queries individually in SSMS and then you will immediately know if your guess was correct.

Comment: yes i am only getting result of 1st query, even though individually running the sub quries are giving results(individually)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe those queries return many duplicates. Try to use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`, because the later removes duplicate rows.

Comment: @work still got only one row? Then you need to test these sub-queries one by one. Because it seems that some of them do not return anything.

Comment: the 3rd query has last 3 rows empty SELECT a.a1,d.d1,d.d2,'' 
           FROM a,d 
          WHERE a.a4 = d.d4) =>d.d1 and d.d2 are empty only a.a1 has value

Answer (score 0):

Use `NULL`, rather than an empty string:

```
   SELECT a.a1, b.b1, NULL, NULL
     FROM a
     JOIN b ON a.a2 = b.b2
   UNION
   SELECT a.a1, c.c1, NULL, NULL
     FROM a
     JOIN c ON a.a3 = c.c3 
   UNION
   SELECT a.a1, d.d1, d.d2, NULL
     FROM a
     JOIN d ON a.a4 = d.d4
   UNION
   SELECT a.a1, e.e1, e.e2, e.e3 
     FROM a
     JOIN e ON a.a5 = e.e5
```

`NULL` is not a value -- it's a placeholder for the lack of any value.

This is necessary because `UNION` statements (including `UNION ALL`) require that the same number of columns returned in all unioned SELECT statements exist, and that the data types should match.

If you are still not seeing data you'd expect, you need to look at each statement individually to be sure it actually returns data.  It's possible the join is not working as you'd expected...

Comment: NULL also giving same result no change .

Comment: If i dont use NULL and '' but if i take only say 2 columns from each query i get result properly. Use of NULL and '' not bringing proper results

Comment: @work: As my last statement says, then you need to review each statement individually.

Comment: individually values are returned

Comment: i think the problem is when there is a column name not found in 1st query in any of the remaining 3 queries , that column name which is not there in first query is not shown while running sql. I think only the common columns are displayed, (some of the columns from 1st query are equla to that used in 2nd,3rd and 4th)

Comment: @work: The column name has nothing to do with a UNION.  Define an alias if you like, but the result will be the same.

Comment: ie, b.b1=c.c1=d.d1=e.e1=(same column name), but other columns like e.e3 , d.d2 are not there in 1st query

Comment: @work: We don't have your data, there's only so much we can do

Answer (score 0):

i suggest running each individual statement by itself and determining if you are getting the results you expect from each one.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using UNION ALL and adding an identifier to each part, something like

```
 SELECT "q1" AS src, a.a1, b.b1, NULL, NULL
 FROM a
 JOIN b ON a.a2 = b.b2
UNION ALL
 SELECT "q2" AS src, a.a1, c.c1, NULL, NULL
 FROM a
 JOIN c ON a.a3 = c.c3 
[...]
```

That way you should at least be able to find out which part of your UNION returns data